# Partial Trace with KroneckerProduct

Tags: matrix, symbolic

I have some symbolic expression of the form

```
X=KroneckerProduct[A,B]+KroneckerProduct[G,F]+...
```

How can I define a partial trace for this, i.e. a function f:

```
f[X]=A*Tr[B]+G*Tr[F]+...
```

?

Answer (score 0):

I have found a solution by

```
Replace[KroneckerProduct[A, B] + KroneckerProduct[G, F], KroneckerProduct[a_, b_] :> (x*Tr[y] /. {x -> a, y -> b}), 1]
```

which gives me

```
A Tr[B] + G Tr[F]
```

However, for a reason I do not know I am not able do the same for single argument, i.e.

```
  Replace[KroneckerProduct[A, B], KroneckerProduct[a_, b_] :> (x*Tr[y] /. {x -> a, y -> b}), 1]
```

gives

```
KroneckerProduct[A, B]
```

Maybe somebody can comment on this...

Comment: The level argument (`1`) specifies that the replacement should only happen on level 1. Since the expression changes from `Plus[KroneckerProduct...]` to `KroneckerProduct`, the rule doesn't apply anymore. You can either use a level specification of `{0,1}`, or just use `ReplaceAll`

Comment: Also, I don't get why you do `x*Tr[y]/.{x->a,y->b}` instead of just `a*Tr[b]`?